# Backyard Space Transportation

Tags: planets, transportation

My novel takes place in an alternate reality where the tropes of nineteen-fifties science-fiction are its reality. A man wants to go to Mars to explore its canals, deserts, and possibly, aliens. He is determined to go there, so I need to find a way a man in the future could build a quick transportation to Mars. Please keep it retro-like

Comment: If a single person is able to build that kind of device at backyard, then why are there no interplanetary transportation companies and why are there no colonies on Mars already? Just asking.

Comment: Don't be bummed by the down votes Galactic5.

Comment: Handwaved coke and mentos based rocket...

Comment: Oh, I love fifties scifi. A modern novel on a world based on those tropes would be a fun read. To keep with the theme, there are two options: a "hard-sciency" hand waved nuclear drive or the rogue physics solutions like "transport beams" and "antigravity engines".

Which path do you want to follow? The generously extrapolated real science route or the pure-magic-tech-that-enables-my-story route?

Answer (score 3):

Nineteen-fifties science-fiction trafficked in impossible science. Since this story has a nineteen-fifties type of setting do thou likewise. The problem with rocket propulsion is that the impossibilities involved are all too real. Real scientists knew this all too well as would many knowledgeable readers in the 1950s. Rockets are improbable possible. The engineering, organizational and economic problems are and were insurmountable.

A 'magic' rocket propulsion system might be feasible but it would require impossible energy densities. This means that the backyard space transportation needs to be powered by a plausible impossibility of a kind that if it really existed it would solve your problem.

Essentially an antigravity drive fits the bill. It would neutralize the pull of Earth's gravity enabling your backyard astronauts to lift off into space. Also, if the antigravity drive produced a net acceleration in any direction, as required, a spacecraft could travel anywhere it wanted to go. Antigravity has the further advantage that travel, even at high rates of acceleration, would be effectively the same as being in free fall. The astronauts could weightless in microgravity or if the drive was adjusted there could be a one gravity field inside the spaceship.

It is worthwhile looking at a few literary examples of backyard spaceship builders. A reading list is provided below.

James Blish, *Welcome to Mars* (1967)
 --- an antigravity drive story

Harry Harrison, *The Daleth Effect* (1970)
 --- an antigravity tale

Harry Harrison, *Star Smashers of the Galaxy Range* (1973)
 -- parodies Smith's *The Skylark of Space*, but has a backyard spaceship of a comical kind

E E Smith, *The Skylark of Space* (1928)
 --- very dated, but has a classic field drive

Robert A Heinlein, *Rocketship Galileo* (1950)
 --- uses nuclear rocket propulsion; not recommended for use in SF.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the 1950 era tropes are pure examples of [handwavium](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum?from=Main.Handwavium). Everyone already knows that you need a rocket to get to Mars, but rocket scientists like Werner Von Braun's detailed calculations revealed you need a massive space infrastructure and an entire *fleet* of rocketships to get to Mars. (VonBraun actually wrote a book about this called [Das Marsprojekt](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL4460018W/Das_Marsprojekt), which is a fascinating read in its own right).

[image]

*Doing it the hard way*

The backyard astronaut gets around annoying impediments like the Rocket Equation, the need for high density energy sources like highly enriched uranium and other roadblocks by inventing some alternative way of bypassing the laws of physics.

This is pretty tough to do, since the laws of physics are enforced at all times and in all places, but your backyard inventor is pretty smart, determined or ignorant of how the physical universe works, so comes up with a solution. A popular work around in that era was a "reactionless drive". One rather fascinating "real life" example was the [Dean Drive](https://infogalactic.com/info/Dean_drive), which attracted a lot of attention before fading into obscurity. Like a lot of these sorts of proposals (and strangely, in common with many "perpetual motion" machines), the principle was unbalanced motion, so your inventor can have a contraption of off axis shafts, whirling weights and so on to move the spaceship. (A bit off topic, but the so called EM drive purports to do the same thing using microwaves in asymmetric resonant cavities).

[image]

*The easy way (sort of)*

This is "believable" in the sense that a mechanical genius could conceivably build such a thing (perhaps needing a few military surplus items like a gas turbine engine to rotate the device at the appropriate speed), and he most likely won't be able to explain how the device work in quantitative terms, meaning you, the author, are also free to handwave the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using preWW2 SF concepts, there are a couple of ways I can imagine one might get to Mars.

1. Discovery of an ancient machine capable of the feat.  I am thinking along the lines of the Eagle of Regiomontanus.

http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Regiomontanus

> He is known for having built one of the most famous automata, the
>   wooden eagle of Regiomontanus, which flew from the city of Koenigsberg
>   to meet the emperor, saluted him, and returned. He also built an iron
>   fly of which it is said it flew out of Regiomontanus's hands at a
>   feast, and taking a round, returned to him.

Regiomontanus was 15th century but your machine could be of whichever civilization you choose.

2. Alien flight tech.  This would be something like coming into possession of a crashed flying saucer.
3. Instantaneous transport.  John Carter reaches Barsoom by some unexplained *Avatar*-like astral projection - his Earth body stays in a cave and gets dusty and he gets a new one on Mars.  Or you could zip thru a wormhole as they did in *Stargate*, after discovering the ancient alien artifacts.

But you want high 50s SF.  The tropes of 1950s SF are much influenced by the experience of WW2 and technological war.   I think that is where you should start.  Your hero is a jet engine technician who did some flying in the war.  With his team (which should include a Von Braun equivalent) they are working on captured German rocket plane prototypes like the ME163 Komet.  http://nationalinterest.org/blog/the-buzz/the-super-scary-legend-nazi-germanys-me-163-rocket-fighters-18494
[image]

After making modifications and additions the hero takes the plane for a test flight and finds the plane has become uncontrollably fast.   Unable to slow down and getting too hot from atmospheric friction, he pulls up in hopes of cooler air and leaves the atmosphere.  As he flies through space he is able to crawl backwards through the plane and address the problem, but by the time he has regained control he is approaching the Red Planet.

Comment: Either the pilot of the interplanetary Komet is crawling at an astronomically slow rate or its acceleration would be so great for him to be approaching the Red Planet in that, apparent, time frame he should have been reduced to a red smear. However, glad to see someone realizes that John Carter must have acquired a new body on Barsoom while his old one languished in a cave in Arizona.

Answer (score 1):

To make a garage-built spacecraft possible, it has to be **small**. Not like the multi-stage [Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V) or even the [Redstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Redstone_Launch_Vehicle), much smaller. To make that happen, you need an engine technology with a higher [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse).

- Take an *unobtainium* chemical rocket. Don't spell out what kind of fuel you are using, just that it is several times better than kerosene/oxygen.
- Take an *atomic* rocket to heat reaction mass instead of a mere chemical reaction. Everybody knows that atomic power is more powerful than chemical combustion.

The pro of atomic drives is that they're more realistic, the con is that they require a [Manhattan Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project). With a specific impulse in the five figures, you can do not just [single stage to orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-stage-to-orbit) but single stage to Mars and back.